# How to read message from windows server service bus using wcf?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, azureservicebus

I am publishing the xml on the windows server service bus using

```
    BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage("Xml as string");
```

Trying to read in wcf service as below

```
    //System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message
    public void TopicReader(Message message) 
            {

            }
```

Config settings as

```
     <bindings>
     <netMessagingBinding>
            <binding name="messagingBinding" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00"
                   receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" sessionIdleTimeout="00:01:00"
                   prefetchCount="-1">
              <transportSettings batchFlushInterval="00:00:01" />
            </binding>
          </netMessagingBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="securityBehavior">
              <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
                <tokenProvider>

                  <windowsAuthentication>
                    <stsUris>
                      <stsUri value="https://MahindeName/Namespace" />

                    </stsUris>
                  </windowsAuthentication>
                </tokenProvider>
              </transportClientEndpointBehavior>

            </behavior>
```

endpoint name="TopicReader" listenUri="sb://MahindeName/Namespace/TopicName/subscriptions/Sub"
                      address="sb://MahindeName/Namespace/TopicName" binding="netMessagingBinding" bindingConfiguration="messagingBinding"
                      contract="Service.ITopicReader" behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior"

Service is hosting without any error, but we are not able to receive the message and the delivery count is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you need to get quite a number of things right before the receive will happen. My advice is to also try to publish using WCF and once you're able to publish successfuly via wcf then that config is good for receiving as well.